# Email an xml file using a generic button on a livecycle designer form?

Tags: javascript, livecycle

I found the following script on another thread (13056369):

```
// Replace with actual path to the field which contains the subject:
var subject = form1.SF1.TxtFld1.rawValue.concat("_"+ form1.SF1.TxtFld2.rawValue);

var myDoc = event.target;
try {
    myDoc.mailDoc({
        bUI: false,
        cTo: 'me@email.org', // Replace with actual receiver mail address.
        cSubject: subject,
        cSubmitAs: "PDF"
    });
} catch (e) {
    // exception handling...
}
```

The above works great.  However, I would like to modify it to email the xml file instead of a pdf file.  Any help on how to modify the above script would be greatly appreciated.

If you have another way that I can accomplish the same task, just let me know and I'll give it a try.  I just need the subject line to use the two text fields identified in the above script, and the file needs to be xml not pdf.

I am using LiveCycle Designer 9.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cSubLine = "Subject line"; 
var cBody = "Body of the email";
var cEmailURL = "mailto:theEmailYouWant@gmail.com?cc=" + "&subject=" + cSubLine + "&body=" + cBody;

event.target.submitForm({
    cURL: cEmailURL,
    cSubmitAs:"XML",
    cCharSet:"utf-8"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an email submit button instead of custom code to handle the parameters such as submission data type, email address and subject. This is a preferred approach rather than adding custom code in LiveCycle ES.

I did include an image of an email address button but cant post it since I'm a n00b to Stack Overflow. Do let me know if you have any other questions.